# Selection with condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The problem statement is :

16 people are occupying seats round a table. If ever person refuses to work with any of his neighbours, in how many ways can a committee of 6 can be made with those persons?

How do I approach this type of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly to facilitate the explaning in the answer let's give the persons numbers $1,2,\dots,16$ clockwise.

Pick one person out - let's say number $1$ - to be the somehow virtual chairman of the committee.

Now we start looking for tuples $\left(n_{1},\dots,n_{6}\right)$
where the $n_{i}$ are positive integers and $n_{1}+\cdots+n_{6}=10$.

These $n_{i}$ stand for the cardinality of the gaps, i.e. consecutive
persons that are not in the comittee.

If e.g. $n_{1}=2$ and $n_{2}=1$ then persons with number $4$ and
number $6$ are the next in the committee.

Applying [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) we find $\binom{4+5}{5}=126$ possibilities and each tuple $\left(n_{1},\dots,n_{6}\right)$
represents a committee having person $1$ as chairman.

There are $16$ choices for the chairman so we come to $16\times126=2016$
possibilities.

However, every possible committee has been counted $6$ times because there are
$6$ choices for the chairman, so we end up with: $$\frac{2016}{6}=336$$
possibilities.

Comment: Nice! Is there any other way to do this? Just asking!

Comment: I guess there is, but not that I can think of now. My source of inspiration is exhausted now and needs some rest :-).

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for **another way**

Glue an "**u**nchosen" to the right of every "**c**hosen", $\fbox {cu}$
thus number of *entities* becomes $6+4=10$

Place the glued entities in $\binom{10}{6} = 210$ ways,
but since you are allowing entities only $10$ starting points instead of 16, multiply by $\frac{16}{10}$,
thus number of committees = $\frac{16}{10}\cdot 210 = 336$

Comment: Can you elaborate more on from the place the glued entities part?

Comment: By glueing together an unchosen person to the right of a chosen committee member, we create $6$ boxes ($=12$ people) and $4$ other unchosens. Now whichever way we arrange the boxes and "singles", we have ensured that committee members are never neighbours.

Comment: You are welcome !